# How to Dislay Relation value in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I am working with the Django admin Panel, and I am doing setup for product variations for an eCommerce website, I created multiple tables in my database for variations, which is related to each other. Now I want to display `size` and `flavour` in the admin panel, suppose there are 3 types of size `small`, `medium` and `large` then it should be shown in `Size` dropdown in my Django admin panel, and the same process for `flavours`, but right now all `sizes` and `flavours and coming in the single dropdown, please check my code and let me know how I can solve this issue.

Here are my `models.py` file

```
class Variants(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=285, default=None)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[image: and it's]

and here is variationoption code, it will store `variation table` id

```
class VariantOptions(models.Model):
    variant=models.ForeignKey('Variants', related_name='var_option', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=285)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[image]

and here are my `skuoption` table code

```
class SkuOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variantoption=models.ForeignKey('VariantOptions', related_name='sku_option', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sku=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    qty=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku
```

[image]

Here is my `admin.py` file code, where I am registering models for the relationship

```
class SkuOptionAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    fieldsets = [(None, {'fields':['sku','price','qty','variantoption']})]
    model = SkuOption
```

and this is my admin panel image
[image]

my all `variationoption` is coming in the single dropdown, but I want different for `size` and `flavour`, and there would be 2 dropdowns, one for `size` and another for `flavour`, and these options will come from `variant` and `variantoption` table, so please let me know what code I can do in my admin.py file here `fieldsets = [(None, {'fields':['sku','price', 'qty','variantoption']})]`, so that I can get both dropdowns.
If you have new suggestion then plese share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

Add variant foreign key to skuoption table, not to variantoption table:

```
class VariantOptions(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=285)
  created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name


class SkuOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant=models.ForeignKey('Variants', related_name='var_option', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variantoption=models.ForeignKey('VariantOptions', related_name='sku_option', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sku=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    qty=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku
```

Comment: it's giving me `variants` table data '`size` and `flavour`, but I want `variantoption` table data in dropdown according to `variant_id`, please look at in the above image, there are `variant_id=1` then all `sizes` should be in a new dropdown in my admin panel, and if `vriant_id=2` then all `flavour` should be in a new dropdown in my admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your attributes and attributes values to be dynamic, To get different size(attribute) and flavor(value) I suggest you to create a table with  product, attribute and foreign key as following:

```
  class Attributes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True,null=True)

class AttributeTerms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank =True)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attributes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True, blank=True,)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True,null=True)
    

class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attributes', default=None)
    attributes = models.ForeignKey(Attributes,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attributes', default=None)
    values = models.ForeignKey(AttributeTerms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attributes', default=None)



class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(ProductAttribute,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, default=None)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    stock_threshold = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length= 250, default=None)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

******And on admin.py******

```
class ProductAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):
       model = ProductAttribute


class ProductVariationInline(admin.TabularInline):
       model = ProductVariant
       
       
class ProductVariant(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [ProductAttributeInline,
              ProductVariationInline,
              ]

admin.site.register(Products, ProductVariant)
```